# How to bind two different controls to two different data sources in a single datagrid cell dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a datagrid which i am populating from sql query which has some Fee columns of bool values which shows status of fee (paid/unpaid). I want each cell of that column to display a label and a  button, label will show the amount of fee(which i have in a separate table in sql) and button will show the status if paid or unpaid based on the bool value.

I have changed the template of that fee column dynamically by detecting the bool column by using the following code which i found online, also used a value converter to change the value from bool to string for (paid/unpaid)  and got the button i wanted, but for the label i am stuck cause i don't know how to set the binding of label for the desired result.

```
        public class MyDataGridTemplateColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
    {
        public string ColumnName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
        {
            // The DataGridTemplateColumn uses ContentPresenter with your DataTemplate.
            ContentPresenter cp = (ContentPresenter)base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
            // Reset the Binding to the specific column. The default binding is to the DataRowView.
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(cp, ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding(this.ColumnName));
            return cp;
        }
    }

    private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
        {
            MyDataGridTemplateColumn col = new MyDataGridTemplateColumn();
            col.ColumnName = e.PropertyName;  // so it knows from which column to get MyData
            col.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("newTemplate");
            e.Column = col;
            e.Column.Header = e.PropertyName;
        }
    }
```

[I have achieved this till now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkLop.jpg)

Comment: If I understand your requirement correctly, you don't have to have two different templates, you can achieve what you want with [converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [datatriggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?view=netframework-4.7.2). All you need is a [ViewModel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) that finds and holds all the relevant data from your different Model classes

Comment: Thanks for the response @PouyaAbadi , I am using converters and data triggers for button and it works pretty well but for the label, binding is a problem cause the DataGridTemplateColumn is using datagrid's Fee column for binding, which only has bool values. If i try to bind each label by Relativesource to a list of Amounts which i populated from sql table, it just calls the list.ToString() method for every label, how can i set the binding for all labels to pick a single unique record in list? and i am not using MVVM pattern.

Comment: may I suggest using the mvvm pattern for this case? I'm pretty sure it can be done without it, however without knowing more about your data model, the best suggestion I can think of is to use mvvm. Create a "ViewModel" class. Add one property per cell, and two properties for the Admission fee cell. You'll then be able to modify the property's getter as your heart desires